# Typescript doesn't respect the `exclude` array

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I recently downloaded a library ([`rn-range-slider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-range-slider)), and now whenever I run `tsc`, it fails because the types are incorrect.

Everything was working just fine before I installed it and now I have no idea how to omit this library from the typescript compiler.

What's been making me pull my hair out is that I already have `node_modules` listed in the `exclude` array in tsconfig. There's little that I haven't tried yet, so any help would me much appreciated.

I also created a `decs.d.ts` file with the contents:

```
declare module 'rn-range-slider';
```

However this didn't help at all.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "decs.d.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*/**", "node_modules/rn-range-slider/**", "node_modules/rn-range-slider/*/**"]
}
```

And here's the base tsconfig that came from Expo:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

What's going on here? This is how I import and use the component:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import RangeSlider from 'rn-range-slider';

type SliderProps = any;
export const Slider = React.memo<SliderProps>(
    ({
        ...props
    }) => {
        return (
            <RangeSlider
                {...props}
            />
        );
    },
);
```

Comment: Share the complete error message as well